# NavigationView -> headerLayout -> ImageButton -> onclick results in IllegalStateException in ContextThemeWrapper

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout, androiddesignsupport, navigationview

In the `headerLayout` of a `NavigationView` (on the left side of a `DrawerLayout` app) I have an `ImageButton`, which should represent ability to add a social network account:

[image]

Here is the **activity_main.xml** with the `NavigationView`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="#FFF"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/drawer_item_text"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/drawer_item_text"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/header_left"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_left"/>
```

And here the **header_left.xml** with the `ImageButton`:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/account"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_account_plus_white_24dp"
    android:background="@color/drawer_header_bg"
    android:onClick="showAccounts"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
    />
```

In the **MainActivity.java** I have defined the click handler method:

```
public void showAccounts(View v) {
    Log.d(TAG, "accounts button clicked");
}
```

Unfortunately, the app crashes on the `ImageButton` click with:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method showAccounts(View) in the activity class android.view.ContextThemeWrapper for onClick handler on view class android.widget.ImageButton with id 'account'
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4013)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4785)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19858)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
 Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: showAccounts [class android.view.View]
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:664)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:643)
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4006)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4785)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19858)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
```

Why does it happen and how to work around the problem please? (Besides adding `onClickListener` in **MainActivity.java**).

I have another `ImageButton` in the `Toolbar` of the same app - and its *onclick* handler is called in **MainActivity.java** just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem, and I fixed it with the next way:

first remove the attribute app:headerLayout from the android.support.design.widget.NavigationView, because we need add this programmatically.

Now in your class when use the NavigationView do something like this:

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
headerView = navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.header_left);
ImageButton accountButton = (ImageButton) headerView.findViewById(R.id.account);
accountButton.setOnClickListener...
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. Thanks Javier for help me to understand.

Another solution, without removing app:headerLayout from xml, can be done:

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
ImageButton accountButton = (ImageButton) headerView.findViewById(R.id.account);
accountButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```